# Docker Apache Proxy point to running Python Script

Tags: python, apache, docker, proxy, virtualhost

Hoping that someone can help me understand what I have done wrong in my setup. I have a Ubuntu Server set up with Docker. I have an Apache container(running on port 80) set up to run as a Proxy and use Virtual Hosts to point to a port dependent on domain name.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myDomain.com
   ServerAlias www.myDomain.com

   <Proxy *>
      Allow from localhost
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://myDomain:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

For a specific docker container, I have a python script running on port 80 (confirmed by going to *SERVER_IP:PORT*) however when I go to the domain it only shows the default apache page (on the apache proxy container)

I have also got other containers running LAMP stacks (with volume mapped to a folder on the apache proxy container. example `/var/www/html` is mapped to `/var/www/html/website.com`) and they work correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can't see the output of the python script at that domain but am able to when navigating to *IP_ADDR:PORT*? **All help and better ideas of a setup is appreciated!! THANK YOU!!!**

EDIT: Python script is running under `/root/pythonscript/` could this be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is running on localhost? so you want to collect on the domain but route to localhost?

I also assume that the python script is running on port 8080? And that apache is running on port 80?

Try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myDomain.com
   ServerAlias www.myDomain.com

   <Proxy *>
      Allow from localhost
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks... I found that both `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and `ProxyPass / http://myDomain:8080/` had the same output. I have the apache proxy container running on web servers port 80 and the python container running on port 8080 with the python script running on 80. I have just tried running the python script on port 8080 as well thinking that might have been it... But unfortunately it results in the same output (apache default page from the apache proxy container? does that set up make sense? I apologise if I haven't explained it well?

Answer (score 0):

OMG! I am sorry to waste your time, stupid me didn't run `a2ensite domain.com.conf` before I reloaded apache2 service... I apologise... That has fixed the issue!